# Did I break my DB while changing ManyToMany field in Django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, manytomanyfield

So I had a ForeignKey field and I needed to convert it to a ManyToManyField. When I ran the migration it gave this error:

> ValueError: Cannot alter field core_app.IndieTrack.contributors into
>   core_app.IndieTrack.contributors - they are not compatible types (you
>   cannot alter to or from M2M fields, or add or remove through= on M2M
>   fields)

So I said, "fine," and I reverted it back to the ForeignKey, thinking I would come up with an alternate solution. But when I migrated again (back to the original state), it gave me the same error.

Now I can't migrate any changes at all. No matter what I do I get the same error.

Here's the whole traceback:

```
python3.4 manage.py makemigrations core_app              Migrations for 'core_app':
  0034_auto_20150521_0740.py:
    - Create model UserTrack
    - Remove field contributors from indietrack
    - Delete model IndieTrack
    - Alter field tracks on album
python3.4 manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: sessions, home, auth, admin, ipn, beat_store, blog, core    _app, contenttypes
Running migrations:
  Applying core_app.0024_auto_20150521_0634...Traceback (most recent call last):

Running migrations:
  Applying core_app.0024_auto_20150521_0634...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/thephltr/webapps/who_pro/lib/python3.4/Django-1.7.7-py3.4.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/thephltr/webapps/who_pro/lib/python3.4/Django-1.7.7-py3.4.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/thephltr/webapps/who_pro/lib/python3.4/Django-1.7.7-py3.4.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/thephltr/webapps/who_pro/lib/python3.4/Django-1.7.7-py3.4.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/thephltr/webapps/who_pro/lib/python3.4/Django-1.7.7-py3.4.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 533, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/home/thephltr/webapps/who_pro/lib/python3.4/Django-1.7.7-py3.4.egg/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 27, in handle_noargs
    call_command("migrate", **options)
  File "/home/thephltr/webapps/who_pro/lib/python3.4/Django-1.7.7-py3.4.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 115, in call_command
    return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/home/thephltr/webapps/who_pro/lib/python3.4/Django-1.7.7-py3.4.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/thephltr/webapps/who_pro/lib/python3.4/Django-1.7.7-py3.4.egg/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 161, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=options.get("fake", False))
  File "/home/thephltr/webapps/who_pro/lib/python3.4/Django-1.7.7-py3.4.egg/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 68, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(migration, fake=fake)
  File "/home/thephltr/webapps/who_pro/lib/python3.4/Django-1.7.7-py3.4.egg/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 102, in apply_migration
    migration.apply(project_state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/thephltr/webapps/who_pro/lib/python3.4/Django-1.7.7-py3.4.egg/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 108, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, project_state, new_state)
  File "/home/thephltr/webapps/who_pro/lib/python3.4/Django-1.7.7-py3.4.egg/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 139, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/home/thephltr/webapps/who_pro/lib/python3.4/Django-1.7.7-py3.4.egg/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 454, in alter_field
    new_field,
ValueError: Cannot alter field core_app.IndieTrack.contributors into core_app.IndieTrack.contributors - they are not compatible types (you cannot alter to or from M2M fields, or add or remove through= on M2M fields)
```

And here's my model:

```
class IndieTrack(models.Model):
    duration = models.CharField(max_length=12, default='0:00')
    track_title = models.CharField(max_length=95)
    track_number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    contributors = models.ForeignKey(Artist, null=True, blank=True)
    extra_info = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.track_title
```

I have changes that I need to make. Any insight will be greatly appreciated.

I'm using PostgreSQL

Comment: Does that error appear when you `makemigrations`? If not, what's the result of `makemigrations`?

Comment: makemigrations works fine with no errors. I'll add that stuff to the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that field was all you changed, I'm going to suggest going back to your migrations folder and deleting the ones created after you tried changing it to a ManytoMany Field. Since you've already created said migration, and Django runs them in order, it's going to keep trying to run it because the migrations you've made after that depend on it and that error will keep appearing. This is what I do when such happens for my own sanity.

If you have other fields you changed, perhaps you could enter that migration file and remove the bit relevant to that field.

Comment: Sounds like what I want. I'm in the Migrations folder but there's just a bunch of py files. How do I find a "migration?"

Comment: Look at them from the most current down. But going off your traceback, the file in question is `core_app.0024_auto_20150521_0634`. So you could just delete that one and the ones created afterwards. Also after you've done that, if there's no content in the db, delete that Foreign Key field and create a new one that's ManytoMany with the same name.

Comment: Even when I go back to OLD migrations from before the table existed, it won't let me delete the table and it won't accept any version of the table. I'm very confused and frustrated! Are there migrations saved somewhere I can't see and it's loading them up each time?

Comment: I kept getting the same ValueError.  The solution was to delete the migration files from within the app's folder. I was just deleting the migration records from the DB, but I had to delete the actual migrations.

Comment: oh, I didnt know you were doing that, I wrote in my first sentence to go to the migrations folder. But glad it worked out.